# Is there a urllib bug with unquoting 'ß'?

Tags: python, decode, urllib

I'm scraping a german website with python and want to save files with the original name that I get as an url encoded string.

e.g. what I start with:

> 'GA_Pottendorf_Wiener%20Stra%C3%9Fe%2035_signed.pdf'

what I want:

> 'GA_Pottendorf_Wiener Straße 35_signed.pdf'

```
import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.unquote(file_name_quoted)
```

Above code works fine with 99% of the names until they contain an 'ß', which should be a legit
utf-8 character.

But I get this:

> 'GA_Pottendorf_Wiener Stra�e 35_signed.pdf'

```
>>> urllib.parse.quote('ß')
'%C3%9F'
>>> urllib.parse.unquote('%C3%9F')
'�'
```

Is this a bug, or a feature that I don't understand?

(and please feel free to correct my way of asking this question, it's my first one)

Comment: This looks more like a font or terminal encoding issue. The `unparse` command produces a string that displays ß in my terminal.

Comment: What does `urllib.parse.unquote('%C3%9F').encode()` return (with and without an explicit `'utf8'` argument to `encode`)?

Comment: What does `hex(ord(urllib.parse.unquote('%C3%9F')))` return?

Comment: Thanks guys, it seems like @chepner is right and my PyCharm console just displays it wrong and my mistake is somewhere completely different.